# Catel.Fody in WPF .NET Core 3.1 / .NET 5.0 - Namespace not Found Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, catel

I am having an issue using `Catel.Fody` in a .NET Core 3.1 WPF application. I add the NuGet package `Catel.Fody` and the `FodyWeavers.xml` file is generated, shown below.

The `using Catel.Fody;` statement gives an error: `the namespace Catel cannot be found`.

Is Catel.Fody not compatable with .NET Core WPF?

```xml
<Weavers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FodyWeavers.xsd">
  <Catel />
</Weavers>
```

Edit: I'm following the MVVM pattern and my Views & ViewModels are in the UI layer which is where I need to use Catel.Fody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue and solved it by replacing the following code in the project file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Catel.Fody">
  <Version>4.7.0</Version>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

With:

```
<PackageReference Include="Catel.Fody" Version="4.7.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
```

The problem was with the `<IncludeAssets>` element. It needs to have `compile` listed in it's content. By removing the `<IncludeAssets>` element the default value of `all` is used.

Further information on Package Reference available on [Microsoft NuGet Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files).

Answer (score 2):

They should all be compatible. Please check out the Orc components (https://github.com/wildgums). These are all.net core 3.1 and.net 5.0 compatible and use Catel.Fody.

Comment: Thanks. However, I could not find anything useful for this instance in the WildGums GitHub. I have used Catel.Fody in a .net standard 2.0 library no problem. I am using a blank WPF .net core 3.1 app in VS 2019. Is there anything aside from Catel.Fody that I need to have that namespace become available in the WPF app? I also have Catel.Core and Catel.MVVM installed.

Comment: No, it should work, but without a repro it's hard to tell. Please check out LogViewer, Csv Text Editor and Orchestra as well. All open source WPF apps using Catel (and Fody).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not sure why but when I copied the package references from LogViewer to my WPF app and built it Catel.Fody is suddenly available. Hopefully I will be able to carry over this fix in my original project. Even after removing all references except Catel.Fody/MVVM/Core. Here's the repo with the projects that still are in error if you're interested. However, it might just be my machine needs a reboot. https://github.com/juicebyjustin/catel-fody-wpf-core-3-1/tree/master/CatelFodyWpfCoreTest